# How to have a TOC with a specific character style?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, character-styles, table-of-contents

With TOC user can call a series of texts in order of document with a specific paragraph style to create a table of content.

Is it possible to do the same calling character styles?

Any tricks like doing with TOC?

Comment: Hi Roozbeh, I don't know is is possible what you are trying to do, but, did you try creating a paragraph style with a GREP style to apply a character style to all the characters of this paragraph?

Comment: Hi Rozbeh.  Have you checked the Adobe documentation on [Character and Paragarph styles in Indesign](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/paragraph-character-styles.html)?

Comment: @Danielillo Hey there dan, I'm about to create a index of the words have "Underline" character style.

Comment: @billy-kerr Hi Billy, Yes i checked it and know what are differences.

Comment: This sounds like something that’s most easily done by scripting, because unfortunately I don’t think there is a corresponding TOC function for character styles. Should be quite easily scriptable, though. Alternatively, you can use an already existing script to make an index based on character styles (such as [this one](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/index_charstyles.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, is not an InDesign feature, but there are some tricks.

- Adding a **Footnote** to the word with the same word as a content
- This footnote has its own paragraph style
- From the TOC, call the **footnote paragraph style** and place it with a different paragraph style
- Set the original footnote paragraph style to invisible (horizontal scale=1%, vertical scale=1%)

---

[image]

*In this .gif example, after assigning the RED character style to the word Dipsam, create a footnote with the same word. When updating the TOC, the word Dipsam appears together with the page number in the right position.*

Comment: holy cats, I would upvote this 10 times just to reward you for making that GIF.

Comment: Hmmm... good trick... but adding a lot of words into footnotes is a pain I guess! but this trick homes so handy sometimes. thank you for mentioning! ;)

Comment: Neat workaround i guess, but still scripting would be much cleaner.